# How to make better an arrow function which changes icon depending of a type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I did an arrow function to be able to change the icon based on a type coming from DB. The type is `preferredContactWay === <Type>`

I would like to write it better to be able also to reuse this maybe as a helper to some other component. Also, there is added a tooltip to give a  message on hover.

The arrow function

```
const iconContactWay = () => {
    if (preferredContactWay === 'Phone call' || !preferredContactWay) {
      return (
        <StyledTooltip title="Contact by Phone Call">
          <Phone />
        </StyledTooltip>
      );
    } else if (preferredContactWay === 'Email') {
      return (
        <StyledTooltip title="Contact by Email">
          <Email />
        </StyledTooltip>
      );
    } else if (preferredContactWay === 'SMS') {
      return (
        <StyledTooltip title="Contact by SMS">
          <Sms />
        </StyledTooltip>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: "write it better" can mean many different things to different people. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean in that way is like more efficient and be able to reused like in other components which would in the necessity to use the same icons in this changing way

Answer (score 1):

I'd make an object indexed by `preferredContactWay`, whose values are the components - then you can just look up the appropriate component on the object. To make the `title`, just use the `preferredContactWay` string (concatenated with `Contact by`):

```
const contactComponents = {
  'Phone call': Phone,
  Email,
  SMS: Sms
};
const iconContactWay = () => {
  const contactType = preferredContactWay || 'Phone call';
  const ContactComponent = contactComponents[contactType];
  return (
    <StyledTooltip title={`Contact by ${contactType}`}>
      <ContactComponent />
    </StyledTooltip>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Either this:

```
const iconContactWay = () => {
  let [text, component] = ['Contact by Phone Call', <Phone />];

  if (preferredContactWay === 'Email') {
    [text, component] = ['Contact by Email', <Email />];
  } else if (preferredContactWay === 'SMS') {
    [text, component] = ['Contact by SMS', <Sms />];
  }

  return <StyledTooltip title={text}>{component}</StyledTooltip>;
};
```

Or put them in an object like so: `{ key: { text: '...', component: </> }, ... }`